# Spring MVC and Ajax error 406

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run an ajax method with spring MVC, but I'm getting the error 406: "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable According to the request" accept "headers"

Controller:

```
@Transactional
@Controller("user")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class HomeController {
@Autowired
private UserDAO daoUser;
@Autowired
private EnterpriseDAO daoEnterprise;
@Autowired
private FuncDAO daoFunc;
@Autowired
private LastPeriodDAO daoLastPeriod;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "redirect:menu";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView menu(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Enterprise enterprise) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/menu");

    Func func = daoFunc.getFunc(user);
    mav.addObject("func", func);
    mav.addObject("enterprise", enterprise);
    mav.addObject("enterpriseList", daoEmpresa.listEnterprise(func));

    return mav;

}
@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamicMenu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<LastPeriod> dynamicOption(@ModelAttribute("enterprise") Enterprise enterprise) {

    System.out.println(enterprise.getCnpj());
    List<LastPeriod> options = daoLastPeriod.getLastPeriod(enterprise);

    System.out.println(options.size());

    return options;
}
```

Request ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function enterpriseSelectChange() {
    var enterprise= $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dynamicMenu',
        data: enterprise,
    })

    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data)
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
$("#cnpj").change(enterpriseSelectChange);
```

});

Form:

```
                <form:form modelAttribute="enterprise" commandName="enterprise" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Olá, ${func.name}</legend>

                    <!-- Select enterprise -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="enterprise">Enterprise</label>

                        <form:select path="cnpj" class="form-control">
                            <form:option value="0" label=" Select"/>
                            <form:options items="${enterpriseList}" itemValue="cnpj"/>
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Please, anyone have any solutions ?

EDIT

Included controller and form

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send to the controller? var enterprise= $(this).serialize(); is this where form serialization happens?

Comment: I am sending an id of a company selected by the User. This id is a parameter to access an options list.

By the time I get the id and realize the query. The error occurs in the response of the request, which can not send that list to mount the elements with javascript.

Comment: If you are sending an `id` which is of type string or long, then you controller method should not be taking `@ModelAttribute("enterprise") Enterprise` as input. So are you sending Model object back to your controller?

Comment: I'm getting the ajax request an enterprise object. I will put the controller and the form in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thank you for your help.

I had a problem in the spring configuration, which was configured an `JsonViewResolver` , `configureContentNegotiation` , `contentNegotiatingViewResolver` . I think I had to specify a return on the controller.

As just I need a JSON disregarded those settings and is now working.

Personal , first thank you for your help.

I had a problem in the spring configuration, which was configured an JsonViewResolver , configureContentNegotiation , contentNegotiatingViewResolver . I think I had to specify a return on the controller.

As just I need a JSON disregarded those settings and is now working.

I also changed my method because it does not need to receive an object , only one id. Therefore it looked like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamicMenu/{cnpj}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> DynamicOptions(@PathVariable final String cnpj) {

    return daoLastPeriod.getLastPeriod(new Enterprise(cnpj));
}
```

Request ajax:

```
var cnpj = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/myincome/dynamicMenu/' + cnpj,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("success");

        console.log(data[0]);

        for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i].description);
        }

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

406 means "not acceptable". Try to add header content-type when sending the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    url: 'dynamicMenu',
    data: enterprise,
})

.done(function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data)
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the line "headers," Content-type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded '"but still with the same error.

Comment: may be the problem is with this jquery serialize. Try to hardcode it , just for test. try `data : "field1=value1&field2&value2"`

Comment: I did a test on the controller to return string, and it worked ... The problem is when I try to return a list of objects ...

Comment: from the first post i understood that you have a problem when sending data, now you says that actually you have a problem when returning list of objects. please give me your form and `Enterprise` class.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the error message is saying that the server cannot generate a response type that is acceptable to your AJAX call. The server is expecting your "Accept" header to contain a type that it can generate response in.

Try setting the "Accept" header in your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Accept:application/json'
    },
    ...
})
```

Note the difference between the headers

1. "Content-Type" --> request content is of this type/format
2. "Accept" --> I will accept a response in this type/format

The other comment asks you to set your content-type but the error message you posted seems to indicate that you need to set the "Accept" header.

Answer (score 0):

So here is your problem,

You need to return `jsonObject` but actually you are returning the List of LastPeriod Object i.e. `List<LastPeriod>`.

So you need to change in method,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamicMenu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<LastPeriod> dynamicOption(@ModelAttribute("enterprise") Enterprise enterprise) {

    List<LastPeriod> options = daoLastPeriod.getLastPeriod(enterprise);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for(LastPeriod lastPeriod: options){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        //Here put data in jsonObject from lastPeriod like 
        jsonObject.put("name", "populate field from lastPeriod");
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("data", jsonArray);
    return jsonObject.toJSONString();
}
```

Now you will get ajax response as array like.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'dynamicMenu',
    data: enterprise,
    success: function(resp){
        var parseJson = JSON.parse(resp);
        console.log(parseJson.data);
    }
});
```